# Installing 7BEE(java build tool)

Tags: java, compilation

Can someone please help me with 7BEE installation?
[7bee](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Coding-languages-Compilers/7Bee.shtml)
I am going insane here...

it says to only navigate to deploy folder and enter install.
But then it asks to specify the directory of installation. No matter what i enter i can't get the damn thing to work.
It says installation succesfull at the end, but when i type: bee, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation file you need to click is a batch file (install.bat). When you run it by double clicking on its name, it will automatically runs and closes when ends, no matter failed or succeed.
So, to see all the messages, 
1- run cmd as administrator from the start menu (win7) 
2- move to the folder you have copied the 7bee files (i.e., d:>cd 7bee\deploy). 
3- Run install.bat (type install in front of d:\7bee\deploy>). 
the installation starts and it asks you to provide address to install the 7bee. 
4- Press enter or type in your desired folder like d:\7bee and press enter.
Then it will ask to give the java home address. 
5- type in c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0 (it is for me, for you it might differ) and that's all. On successful installation, it gives you a message that "installation successful"
Don't forget to put the path of installation folder into the path (go to environment variable and add c:\program files\7bee\bin" of your desired folder to the path line. Hope it works.